# Forge 1.16.5 Unable to get mutable Windows environment variable map

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

When I try to build my mod I get the error:

> Unable to get mutable Windows environment variable map

some infos about what Im using:

```
    JDK 8.0;
    Minecraft 1.16.5; 
    Forge 20210309-1.16.5; 
    IDEA: Intellij
    Addons: Citadel; JEI;
    Gradle: 4.10.3
```

btw my Windows enviroment variable is set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your windows enviroment variables PATH seems to be incorrectly setup. Do you have a variable called JAVA_HOME where you've set the appropriate path as value for it.

If you have done that, go to system variable and edit PATH, then click new and paste the path to your jdk download

Comment: I fixed the problem, some time ago now so I I could not verify if this solution works, but I think I tried this and it didnt

I think the Windows enviroment varieables have been set corectly, but I had to set them up in intellij as well, as project variables

**In most cases this should work**